logic in having clause
I am trying to filter out the result that both count(device1_id) = 0 and count(device2_id) = 0. However, my logic seems to be incorrect.
select customer_id, count(device1_id), count(device2_id) 
from Table
group by customer_id
having count(device1_id) != 0
and count(device2_id) != 0


Shouldn't that be or not and ?

@Ken, in Oracle, aggregate functions (as COUNT) can not be used in WHERE clause; they have to be moved into HAVING.

@Littlefoot: So sad that Oracle has introduced another deviation from the standards. They must be studying the code they got when they took over MySQL.

From my point of view, it would help if you posted some sample data that illustrates the problem. I have difficulties in understanding what you are trying to do because

if all 3 columns (customer_id, both device IDs) belong to the same table, then count won't return 0
which means that maybe there are two (or more) tables (outer?) joined to each other


Anyway: if you want to "remove" rows (from result set) for which both counts are 0, it means that sum of these counts must be 0 in order for them to be removed, so one option is to use
having not count(device1_id) + count(device2_id) = 0


Use this:
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(case when device1_id<>0 then 1 end)as total_count_device1_id, COUNT(case when device2_id<>0 then 1 end)as total_count_device2_id FROM TABLE GROUP BY customer_id

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
